# Round off a numeric field into 2 decimal places but save the value into DB that is not rounded off using EXTJS MVVM Databinding

Tags: extjs5

How can I round off a numeric field into 2 decimal places and save the value
that is not rounded off into database. I just want the display to have 2 decimals rounded off but the editing mode should accept multiple decimals and save into DB as is. Using EXTJS MVVM Databinding

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use a grid because you mention an editing mode.

Have you tried to define a `renderer` function on the column? E.g.

```
renderer: function (value) {
  return Ext.util.Format.number(value, "0.00");
}
```

(Caveat: I haven't tried it, but I think the rendering and the editing are separate.
And one should add handling of null/undefined values in the code above to increase robustness.)